# Pandas best way to subset a dataframe inplace, using a mask

Tags: pandas, subset, mask, masking

I have a pandas dataset that I want to downsize (remove all values under x).

The mask is `df[my_column] > 50`

I would typically just use `df = df[mask]`, but want to avoid making a copy every time, particularly because it gets error prone when used in functions (as it only gets altered in the function scope).

What is the best way to subset a dataset inplace?

I was thinking of something along the lines of
`df.drop(df.loc[mask].index, inplace = True)`

Is there a better way to do this, or any situation where this won't work at all?

Comment: You mean `view = df.loc[df[my_column] > 50]`?

Comment: I'm always confused by the view vs copy thing in pandas. Essentially I want to give it a condition to drop, and drop inplace. The df.loc[mask].index will give the me indexes to drop, correct?

Comment: Sorry what's wrong with `df = df[mask]`? this will eventually recover the memory for the dropped rows?

Comment: Well `mask` itself is a boolean index

Comment: More error prone, and when used in functions makes a "local" copy, which then has to be returned. I want to do a few alterations in place, not just for memory purposes. `df.drop(df.loc[mask].index, inplace = True)` seems to work, but I expect there might be a better solution (as mine will probably fail on multi-level indexes etc)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by makes a 'local' copy. I'd define df as a global variable, OR make it a class instance. Passing df as an argument to a bunch of functions and then doing changes to df is indeed error-prone.

Answer (score 18):

You are missing the inplace parameter :

`df.drop(df[df.my_column < 50].index, inplace = True)`

Comment: I think you want `<= 50` in the mask to drop, since the OP wanted to keep values `> 50`.

Comment: Is there a method that does the opposite of drop? `filter` ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use `df.query()`

like:

```
bool_series = df[my_column] > 50
df.query("@bool_series",inplace=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this works. Maybe there are better ways?

`df = df.drop(df[df.my_column < 50].index)`

Comment: It would still be a copy and replace, but I'm curious as to why you avoided iloc

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html drop has an inplace flag