# Assigning to dataframe inside for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I want to write a function that takes a dataframe and removes some of its rows:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,5])

def f(df):
    df = df[(df > 2)]
    print(df)

f(a)
print(a)
```

This outputs

```
   0
2  3
3  3
4  5

   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  3
4  5
```

So `a` was not updated here. Is this because the df inside the function body is actually a copy of `a`? If so, how can I rewrite the code to access the genuine dataframe inside the function? More generally, there are various other things I would like to do to dataframes within functions that requires updating the objects passed as inputs to the function, so is there a general solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're really asking I think: [Pandas best way to subset a dataframe inplace, using a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103988/pandas-best-way-to-subset-a-dataframe-inplace-using-a-mask)

How to filter in place.

So in your case it would be (I think):

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,5])

def f(df):
    # df = df[(df > 2)]
    df.drop(df[(df > 2)], inplace = True) # might need df[(df>2)].index
    print(df)

f(a)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify global variable `a`:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,3,5])

def f(df_name):
    globals()[df_name] = eval(f"{df_name}[({df_name} > 2)]")
    print(globals()[df_name])
f("a")
```

Now dataframe named "a" will be modyfied.
Please note that argument of function is string "a" not variable `a` itself.
This works but is not recommended because in code are `globals` and `eval` (read more why: [Why is Global State so Evil?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil))

Easy way is:

```
def f(df):
    return df[(df > 2)]

a = f(a)
```

Function returns just changed dataframe.